# Loading not responding in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to fix the Loading harmful and not responding in Android App? I'm a newbie in Android and I have to do my project and which have bug with Android OS 6.

The app show the group persons on the map and when click on Contact icon, then show the group person lists.

For now, on other OS below OS 6 are working fine and in OS 6 when change to group which have friends or Members, then click on Contact, the loading was stuck and Not responding alert show up. I don't know why.

But on the group which have no members or friends have working fine. I'll show you with the screenshot below.

---

The Image One is no Members and Friends in the Group (Group Name was Test1).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwG4MW1kR1WMSGNHYXNENzVGVUE/view

The Image Two is Choose the Non Member Group and Click on Contact Icon, the list was only me show up.(Work fine with no member in group).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwG4MW1kR1WMcXc5NDc0c09nRXc/view

The Image Three was chosen the Group which have Members or Friends.(The Group name was tt.) The Location pointer was show up in Map.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwG4MW1kR1WMbEdHZUs2NGZPYW8/view

The Image Four is Choose the group which have Members and Click on the Contact Icon, Then the bug was show up. (The loading icon was stuck and after a few seconds or minutes then no responding alert will show up).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwG4MW1kR1WMbF94cjQySkJhSDA/view

Here is LogCat screenshot (Honestly I don't understand how to fix after seeing LogCat) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwG4MW1kR1WMalRrN3psS0h2a28/view

---

```
 @Override
protected View onCreateMainView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start Up");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start Up Condition");
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Start Up SelfCheck");

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(((MainActivity ) getActivity()));
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ico_info_popup_locator);
            builder.setTitle("Already accept location");
            builder.setMessage("Location was already accepted~!");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

            builder.show();

        } else {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(((MainActivity ) getActivity()));
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ico_info_popup_locator);
            builder.setTitle("Location need to accept");
            builder.setMessage("Please Accept to use your location service~!");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }

                private void requestPermissions(String[] strings, int permissionRequestCoarseLocation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }

    map_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, null, false);
    viewContaner = (RelativeLayout) map_layout.findViewById(R.id.viewContaner);
    viewContaner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mapZoomLevel =
            SharePreferencesUtil.getIntValue(ISharePreferencesDefine.KEY_STORE_LEVEL_ZOOM,
                    IConstants.LEVEL_ZOOM_MAP_DEFAULT);
    actionGetUser();
    LocationTracking.getInstance().setOnLocationChangedListener(this);
    initMap();

    return map_layout;
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION) {

        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");

        } else {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(((MainActivity ) getActivity()));
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ico_info_popup_locator);
            builder.setTitle("Location need to accept");
            builder.setMessage("Please Accept to use your location service~!");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }

                private void requestPermissions(String[] strings, int permissionRequestCoarseLocation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But maybe you have problems with **permissions**. I think above android **API Level 23** you get the permission for your app with permission requests while the app is running. But maybe you don't think for the older devices and you don't get the permissions for your app at installation with the **Mainifest.XML**. Maybe this is the thing why you loading stuck. Or you just use a syntax for new devices and old devices cannot resolve it.